# How can I see the contents of an inserted CD?

Tags: 11.10, cd-drive

When opening the CD it doesn't show all files like music and videos etc except power point files. I installed 11.10 Ubuntu using Oracle virtual monitor host OS is windows 7.

Comment: Do you run 11.10 in an virtualbox? or do you have Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows 7 as a dual boot? your question is very confusing and missleading

Comment: CTRL + H shows you any hidden files, but I think you are having a problem with VirtualBox. Help for that is here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Documentation

Comment: It might help us to see a listing of what Windows and Ubuntu each think is on the CD. If you're alright with sharing this information, you can get it by using the `tree` command: 1) Install [Tree for Ubuntu](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/tree) and [Tree for Windows](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gnuwin32/tree-1.5.2.2-setup.exe). 2) Open the terminal and change directory to the inserted CD, using e.g. `e:` in Windows and `cd /media/cdrom` in Ubuntu. 3) Run `tree`, copy and paste the output into [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/), and edit your question here to include a link to it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the command

```
mount -o ro,unhide,uid=1000 /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
```